# using sentinel imports while making policies in terraform

Tags: devops, sentinel, devops-services, devops-insights

Hey i am trying to work with sentinel cli  with terraform i have a policy.sentinel file

```
import "tfplan"
allowed_machine_types = [
    "n1-standard-1",
    "n1-standard-2",
    "n1-standard-4",
    "n1-standard-8",
]

main = rule {
    all tfplan.resources as type, resources {
        all resources as r {
            r.applied.machine_type in allowed_machine_types
        }
    }
}
```

and a config.json file for my imports

```
{
"imports":{
    "tfplan": {
        "path": "./plan"
        }
    }
}
```

the plan is an executable file that is generated after running

```
terraform plan -out plan
```

when i run `sentinel apply -config=config.json policy.sentinel`

my error

```
Runtime error while running the policy:

test.sentinel:1:1: fork/exec ./plan: exec format error

A runtime error is a non-recoverable error and always represents a bug
in the policy. When a runtime error is experienced, the result of the
policy is "false". Please fix the error above and try again.
```

i am not very good at sentinel so what could be issue ? how do we use imports ? i tried going through the documentation and i could not get how to go about it

Answer (score 1):

You can not exec the plan file as it's not executable - you need to exec the terraform plan plugin: that is not available anywhere..

Comment: So what is the alternative to using terraform with sentinel CLI

Comment: to me it looks like you can not - unless you use terraform enterprise